# 100% CPU usage when reading named pipe in Go

Tags: go, named-pipes

I have a short Go program which reads from a named pipe and processes each line as an external process writes to the pipe. The named pipe is created before the program runs using `mkfifo`.

The process is taking up 100% of the CPU when waiting for a new line from the named pipe, even when it's not doing any processing. It's running on Ubuntu 14.04. Any ideas?

```
c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

awaitingExit := false

var wg sync.WaitGroup

go func() {
    for sig := range c {
        awaitingExit = true

        // wait for goroutines to finish processing new lines
        wg.Wait()
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}()

file, err := os.OpenFile("file.fifo", os.O_RDONLY, os.ModeNamedPipe)

defer file.Close()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

// infinite loop
for {
    line, _, _ := reader.ReadLine()

    // stop handling new lines if we're waiting to exit
    if !awaitingExit && len(line) > 0 {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(uploadLog string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            handleNewLine(uploadLog)
        }(string(line))
    }
}

func handleNewLine(line string) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: [Reader.ReadLine()](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadLine) returns an error, are you sure you aren't getting an error in your program? It's always a good practice to check errors, do not ignore them using "_".

Comment: Thanks, checking the error helped me find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "infinite loop" is really *infinite*: you never exit it or jump out of it.

It contains an `if`:

```
// stop handling new lines if we're waiting to exit
if !awaitingExit && len(line) > 0 {
    // code omitted
}
```

But if the condition is false, you're still not getting out of the `for` loop, just continue with another iteration. Once you reach the end of `reader`, this loop will consume 100% of a core because after that it will not wait for anything just trying to read (which will immediately return EOF) and checking the `awaitExit` variable and doing these 2 steps again.

You either need to add condition to the `for` loop to exit sometime, or use a `break` statement to break out of it.

Altered `for` loop with a condition:

```
for !awaitingExit {
}
```

Altered `for` with a `break` statement:

```
for {
    if awaitingExit {
        break
    }
    // code omitted
}
```

Note: if `awaitingExit` variable is changed by another goroutine, you need proper synchronization, or better, use channels for exit signalling.

Comment: It's intentionally infinite, as the program needs to process new writes to the named pipe as they come in.

The `awaitingExit` code is just to gracefully handle termination, i.e. finish the current goroutines first.

Comment: @dchesterton Edited the answer. If there are no more data, `reader` will return EOF immediately, you check the `awaitExit` variable and do these 2 steps endlessly - there is no wait in this code sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your help but `reader` doesn't EOF immediately as it blocks until the other process writes to it as it's a named pipe, not a standard file. It seems this blocking causes the process to max out CPU. I don't know if there's a better way of reading from the named pipe?

Comment: @dchesterton Are you sure about that? And also about that you don't get any other errors? Never discard errors, the least you can do is print them to the consol or `panic`.

Comment: I've logged the error from `ReadLine` and you're right, it does EOF eventually after a few minutes, causing the program to just infinitely loop. Not sure why it doesn't do this immediately and only does it after the process has been idle for a while, but I'll look into it more. Lesson learnt, don't ignore errors!

Comment: It seems the other process would close the named pipe after a period of inactivity on its end. Changing `os.OpenFile("file.fifo", os.O_RDONLY, os.ModeNamedPipe)` to `os.OpenFile("file.fifo", os.O_RDWR, os.ModeNamedPipe)` keeps the file open and seems to fix the issue.